# Field Parameters does not exist. Check spelling

Tags: visualforce

I am trying to get the parameters from the visualforce page. Below is my code

```
<apex:inputHidden value="{!$CurrentPage.Parameters.JobId}" id="targetId" />
```

I used both {!$CurrentPage.Parameters.JobId} and {!CurrentPage.Parameters.JobId} but still getting the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: `{!$CurrentPage.Parameters.JobId}` this should work. are you passing JobId in url ?

Comment: yes its there in the page. The problem is its not allowing to save code itself.. Throwing the error.

Comment: Not sure you can use that with an Input.

Answer (score 2):

Just tried in my org

You can't use `<apex:inputHidden value="{!$CurrentPage.Parameters.JobId}" id="targetId" />`

But If you just add `{!$CurrentPage.Parameters.JobId}` in page then works

```
<apex:page controller="SimpleDynamicController" docType="html-5.0">
    <apex:form >
        {!$CurrentPage.Parameters.JobId}
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

In `apex:inputHidden` always bind the controller variable

If you want to pass this value in controller

Then use `apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('JobId')`

Comment: @VetriselvanMaoharan -- always a good idea to check the VF doc - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_inputHidden.htm?search_text=inputHidden - value attribute = `A merge field that references the controller class variable that is associated with this hidden input field.`.  Ratan has it pegged

Answer (score 0):

You can not do like this.  visualforce attribute takes parameters or variable from apex controller .
 
Solution: you can save the jobID in apex:variable and use it on Visualforce page